# Image component imported from 'next/image' doesn't work

Tags: next.js, frameworks, components, next.js13, nextjs-image

These days I'm studying next.js as seeing video tutorial and I face an unexpected error. I just used Image component which is imported from "next/image" module. But that component couldn't fetch the image and an error looks like a follow picture appears.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1PDR.png)
I think it is because of the version of next.js as there is no problem in next.js 13.2.4 in video tutorial but what I use is version 13.5.1
However, if I use  HTML tag instead of  component, it works!
What is the reason?

I try to find the solution in stack overflow and github but all what they recommend doesn't work!
I can't understand why Image component doesn't work whereas img tag work?
Here are my code.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVUWp.png

Comment: Can you show us your code where you import the `next/image` module and where you use `<Image  ... />`?

Comment: I have added the picture of my code. Then if I use img HTML tag instead of Image component, my profile photo appeared.

Comment: Can you show us the location of your image as well? Also for code it is better to place it as text instead of an image

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use the path directly, you can follow this example :

```js
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import myImage from "image-path";

export default function MyProfilePic() {
  return (
    <section className="w-full mx-auto">
      <Image
        className="border-4 border-black dark: border-slate-500 drop-shadow-x1 shadow-black rounded-full mx-auto mt-8"
        src={myImage}
        width={200}
        height={200}
        alt="Neil Adams"
        priority={true}
      />
    </section>
  );
}
```